# iOS Development on PC/XAML Hot Reload works but images in Asset Catalog Image Sets fail to show

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, hot-reload

Following the instructions, I [enabled `Xamarin Hot Restart`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/dotnetconf-2020-xamarin-recap/) in `Tools > Options > Preview Features > Enable Xamarin Hot Restart` and install iTunes from Microsoft Store. Then opened iTunes, plugged in the iPhone, restarted Visual Studio. Next, configured my Apple Developer Program account. Set the iOS as `Starter Project`, hit F5 and the Xamarin Forms app actually runs on my iPhone. No Mac is even running at that time. Everything works great, but...

The problem is all images that I placed in the [Asset Catalog Image Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=macos) (as it's the preferred way since iOS 9) do not show up.

If I moved the images back to the iOS `Resources` folder with 1x, 2x, 3x sizes, then the images showed up. I tinkered around with different options like `Enable the Mono intepreter` in `iOS Build` options, but that didn't help.

I run the same code on `Visual Studio for Mac`, images in Asset Catalog Image Sets work fine.

What am I still doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Hi, could you share the screenshot of `Assest` and code of Xaml where be used to show the image? In addition, you can have a try with [this official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithimages) to use Asset Image to check whether it works.

Comment: Haven't tried that one, but https://github.com/maddyleger1/PlantLady doesn't work either (same problem as I described, work with images over network, work with images in Resources folder, does not work with images in Asset Catalog Image Sets).

Comment: @Junior Jiang The [official sample WorkingWithImages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithimages/) that you mentioned does not work either

Comment: Okey, I have seen the limitation in your answer. If so, you could mark the answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally see a limitation with Asset Catalogs listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart.